# Alignment issues with gridlayout containing images

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

```
Android Studio 1.2
```

Hello,

I am trying to get this alignment correct to the following wireframe.

[image]

I am only using gridlayout for this and don't want to use linear or relative layout or nested layouts.

I have gotten it close using the following xml. Just need some help with some final touches to make it look perfect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:columnCount="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="16 Mar 2015"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCorrectTxt"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:text="Correct 20"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCorrect"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_good"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:text="22:15"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIncorrect"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:text="Incorrect 18"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIncorrect"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bad"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: (1) Out of interest, any reason you don't want to use other layouts? You don't need it for your particular layout but just wondering. (2) Why are you not using rows and columns? You should have 2 rows, with 6 columns in your grid view and then place your layouts in the correct row/column order instead of relying on the columnSpan and gravity.

Comment: 1) For performance I don't want to use nested layouts. So I am trying to solve this using the gridlayout. And gridlayout is something I am starting to use more often. 2) I have been playing around with the different properties and just using trail and error. So my xml might be a bit messed up. So I thought it was time to ask the experts. Thanks.

Comment: One or two nested layouts don't hurt performance that much. You're making your life hard by trying to save those extra microseconds :-)

Comment: @ant2009 Did you tried the solution explained in (my) answer below? This should achieves your goal with few small changes on your GridLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout (from the pic) looks fairly static - not many moving parts. Why not implement it as a custom `Viewgroup`? Since you're after performance, this would be the way to go.

Positioning of child views will be relative to the `ViewGroup`, rather than the children themselves. Math involved:

**Columns (childLeft & childRight)**

- Divide available width (actualWidth - paddingLeft - paddingRight) into 6 equally spaced columns
- TextViews tvDate & tvTime are flushed left
- TextViews tvCorrectTxt & tvIncorrect are flushed right inside the 4th column
- ivCorrect & ivIncorrect are centered horizontally inside the 5th column
- ivArrow is flushed right in the 6th column

**Rows (childTop & childBottom)**

- We have two rows to display. To have equal spacing above, between, and below the rows, we will align first row's vertical center with `container's height/3` ==> `y = 0.333*availableHeight`; second row's vertical center will sit at `2*container's height/3` ==> `y = 0.666*availableHeight`
- ivArrow will be vertically centered within the available height.

CusViewGroup:

```
public class CusViewGroup extends ViewGroup {   

    // In case we have to explicitly set the viewgroup's height
    private int mDesiredHeight;     

    public CusViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // Attribute array
        int[] attrss = new int[] { android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeightLarge };

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrss);

        // 200 is being used as the default value. 
        // This should actually be defined in res/values/dimens.xml
        // and retrieved using 
        // getResources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.defaultListItemHeight)
        mDesiredHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 200);

        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        final int count = getChildCount();

        final int parentLeft = getPaddingStart();
        final int parentRight = right - left - getPaddingEnd();

        final int parentTop = getPaddingTop();
        final int parentBottom = bottom - top - getPaddingBottom();

        final int availableParentWidth = parentRight - parentLeft;
        final int availableParentHeight = parentBottom - parentTop;
        final int columnWidth = availableParentWidth/6;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final int width = child.getMeasuredWidth(); 
                final int height = child.getMeasuredHeight();

                int childLeft, childTop;

                // We can use the assigned ids and calculate 
                // view positions.
                switch(child.getId()) {
                    case R.id.tvDate:
                        childLeft = parentLeft;
                        childTop = parentTop + availableParentHeight/3 - height/2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tvCorrectTxt:
                        childLeft = parentLeft + columnWidth*4 - width;
                        childTop = parentTop + availableParentHeight/3 - height/2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.ivCorrect:
                        childLeft = parentLeft + columnWidth*4 + (columnWidth - width) / 2;
                        childTop = parentTop + availableParentHeight/3 - height/2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.ivArrow:
                        childLeft = parentRight - width;
                        childTop = parentTop + (availableParentHeight - height) / 2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tvTime:
                        childLeft = parentLeft;
                        childTop = parentTop + 2*availableParentHeight/3 - height/2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.tvIncorrect:
                        childLeft = parentLeft + columnWidth*4 - width;
                        childTop = parentTop + 2*availableParentHeight/3 - height/2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.ivIncorrect:
                        childLeft = parentLeft + columnWidth*4 + (columnWidth - width) / 2;
                        childTop = parentTop + 2*availableParentHeight/3 - height/2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        // We shouldn't be here
                        child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        continue;
                }

                // layout child
                child.layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + width, childTop + height);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        // We're using an exact value for height & MATCH_PARENT for width    
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();

        if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {

            // Use mDesiredHeight if heightMeasureSpec is not
            // measured exactly.
            height = mDesiredHeight;

            // Update heightMeasureSpec
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), height);

        final int count = getChildCount();

        // measure children
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);

            int childWidthMeasureSpec;
            int childHeightMeasureSpec;

            childWidthMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec,
                0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            childHeightMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(heightMeasureSpec, 0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, for the xml, we don't need to define much. Just throw in all the children and let `onLayout(..)` handle placements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- paddingStart=18dp(10dp + 8dp) because ivArrow's size(32dp) - optical square(24dp) = 8dp -->
<your.package.name.CusViewGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:paddingStart="18dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="16 Mar 2015"
        android:textColor="#858585"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCorrectTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Correct 20"
        android:textColor="#858585"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_good"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="22:15"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#858585"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIncorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Incorrect 18"
        android:textColor="#858585"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIncorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bad"/>

</com.appeaser.playground.CusViewGroup>
```

If you want the child views to support padding/margin, you can do so by changing `onLayout(...)` & `onMeasure(...)`. To support RTL, modify `onLayout(...)`.

**Portrait**:

[image]

---

**Landscape**:

[image]

Comment: Whilst this solution is incredibly nice (in terms of the effort and details put into it), I'm not sure it's a good idea to go down this route. If sometime down the line he will need to modify his views, far more effort will be spent on adding these new requirements than if it was simply nested, sensible layouts. I guess that's the cost you have to pay if those milliseconds matter so much. Upvoted regardless because it was very informative and thought me something new.

Comment: @kha Thanks, I do agree that using built-in components has its perks. But then, you also get the overhead involved in generalized `Views/ViewGroups`. The `Viewgroup` above does not take into account gravity, inter-child relations, margin, padding etc. And neither should it. I also don't see an issue with this `ViewGroup's` child-count increasing in the future. `onLayout(..)` will change to accommodate this. Of course, this is a very specific use-case and _will not_ apply to every situation.. (contd)

Comment: @kha ...(contd) From the looks of it, this layout will be used inside a `ListView`. And recyclers can use all the optimization they can get.

Comment: @Vikram, I like the solution as it something extra to learn here (I have always been interested in learning custom views). This layout will be used inside a listview, and depending on the users use, it could have a lot of items that could be added.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to play around with the attribute **columnWeight** in order to tune the size of the cells. I also suggest to assign a specific dimension to your images.

Take a look at my edited version, it gives almost the desired result! (Yes, I'm using different image resources ;) ):

[image]

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:columnCount="6"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:text="16 Mar 2015"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCorrectTxt"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:text="Correct 20"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCorrect"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_good"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivArrow"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_next_item"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:text="22:15"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIncorrect"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0"
        android:text="Incorrect 18"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIncorrect"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_bad"/>


</GridLayout>
```